# Polite forms of address in Ancient Rome

Tags: ancient-rome, everyday-life, latin-language

My Latin dictionary only lists *ere* for *sir*, which is how a slave would address his/her master. But how would a lower status Roman address a person of higher status - for instance, a wage-labourer to an employer, a shopkeeper to a high-status customer, any "commoner" to an aristocrat or, indeed, a slave to one who was **not** his/her master?

Comment: I suppose it was "dominus", or "domina", if female. From this the words don, dom, dame, madame etc. in modern languages is derived. It had a similar evolution as the English work sir.

Comment: Google translate from English to Latin gives "domine" for "sir".

Comment: #Alex This was discussed in a (somewhat unrelated) question, and we were told in no uncertain terms that "domine/domina" would not be used in speech. Also, they both mean "master/mistress" - of a household, of slaves etc - although I do know that under the Empire the emperors were addressed as "Domine", even by high-status correspondents. So - not sure!

Comment: @Alex Beware the Ides of Google Translate! ;)

Comment: I suppose there was no difference depending on who owns the slave. And I do not rely too much on Google translate, I am aware of its shortcomings.

Comment: @Ruby AFAIK, *domine* is the nearest Latin has to *sir* and used rather as it was in 19th century UK or still in parts of USA, as part of polite discourse. NB **Lord Marcus** would be **Domine Marce**, so there's no distinction. Related question https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/27898/polite-forms-of-address-in-ancient-rome

Answer (score 10):

Since posting this question, I've  begun reading *Latin Forms of Address from  Plautus to Apuleius* by Eleanor Dickey OUP 2002,and the question is **considerably** more complex than I ever dreamt! For instance:-

> The masculine *domine*, as far as I can tell, never occurs ...  as an address from a slave to his master. ... when a title is used, it is *ere/era* rather than *domine/domina*. ... No reason for this distinction has ever been proposed, but it seems to me that slaves might have objected to a word meaning 'owner" (*ie domine*) because it put them in the same class as inanimate objects; perhaps they preferred *erus* (which is more often translatable as 'master' than 'owner') because it referred less harshly to their own status. (p 78-79)

*Domine*, conversely, appears to have been used between free, equal men, by children to the head of the household, and Dickey quotes Seneca - "*when we run into people whose names we don't remember, we address them as 'master'"* (Ep 3.1 author's translation.)

"... the contexts are polite but not subservient." observes Dickey (p 88)

Dickey even quotes such usages as *domine* to brothers, and as a term of affectionate respect, as above to fathers. And not just to equals/superiors.

> Don't get too self-satisfied, Cinna, when I call you 'master': I often greet your slave that way too.

(Mart. 5.57* Dickey, p77 author's translation.)

On my main question - how would a slave address a superior **not** his master,  Dickey is clear -

> Slaves addressing free men who are not their masters ... use names and the same other addresses that a free man would use. 
>   Dickey p 234

Dickey makes the point throughout that convention changed over the centuries between Republic (more egalitarian?) and Empire (more deferential?), and the differences between male and female address forms - and I had no idea what a complex and fascinating subject I had embarked on!

Comment: One would indeed imagine the usage of titles probably changed drastically over the nearly 1,000 years of the Republic/Empire's existence in Italy, since it has certainly drastically changed in English in just the last 300 years.

Comment: @T.E.D. Dickey only deals with the period from Plautus to Apuleius, but that's still pretty long! It's interesting that *dominus* has survived in various forms in modern languages, whilst *erus* has totally disappeared!